# IVY - Set the default transitive value

Tags: ivy

How do you override the defalut value of transitive in IVY?

Comment: Not a real question. Please provide more info.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming that you don't want ivy to download the transient dependencies of a **dependency** declaration in your *ivy.xml* file?

### Option 1: Transitive parameter (ivy.xml)

```
<dependency org="foo" name="bar" revision="3.0" transitive="false"/>
```

### Option 2: Configuration mapping (ivy.xml)

If the bar module is held in a Maven repository then mapping the default configuration to the master scope will omit other dependencies

```
<dependency org="foo" name="bar" revision="3.0" conf="default->master"/>
```

### Option 3: Don't use information in POM files (ivysettings.xml)

When downloading from a maven repository setting the usepoms parameter to false will ignore the module's dependencies

```
<ibiblio name="maven" m2compatible="true" usepoms="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Option 3 did the trick for me for gwt. As for another jar, it is still complaining about not finding its dependencies

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set transitive statements in your ant-task (your question really isn't that clear on this), you can use the transitive switch directly (default is "true"):

```
<ivy:resolve ... transitive="false" />
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for - took me much longer than it should have to figure it out. thank you!