# Ivy's transitive="false" gets simply ignored when downloading from Nexus

Tags: java, maven, ivy, nexus

At our company, we are migrating our old ivy repository to Nexus.

After uploading our own artifacts to Nexus, I tried downloading a few projects' dependencies to test the setup, but I'm failing with spring-web. Let me explain how.

Here is the ivy-settings.xml file pointing only to our local Nexus installation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<ivysettings>

    <settings defaultResolver="default" />

    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="nexus" m2compatible="true" root="http://nexus.local/nexus/content/repositories/central/" />
        <ibiblio name="our-nexus" m2compatible="true" root="http://nexus/nexus/content/repositories/repo" />

        <chain name="default" returnFirst="true">
            <resolver ref="our-nexus" />
            <resolver ref="nexus" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

In one of our projects we use Spring Web, but not all of its dependencies, so I declared

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" transitive="false" />
```

This worked fine when using Ivy repository. However today I can't perform an `<ivy:retrieve>` task because it can't find `com.caucho#hessian#3.2.1`

`<ivy:report>` task says that such version of hessian is required by spring-web `3.2.11.RELEASE`

But I have declared `transitive="false"`!!!

Why isn't it working? What am I missing/messing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work. Personally I prefer configuration mappings. Try the following instead:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" conf="default->master" />
```

For more details see:

- [How can I include the Ivy dependency and none of its dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150359/how-can-i-include-the-ivy-dependency-and-none-of-its-dependencies/22159339#22159339)